# Return value when Flux completes?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'd like to return a value (or publisher) after a `Flux` is completed. Here's an example with (pseudo) code that resembles what I'm after:

```
val myId : Mono<String> = fetchMyId()
myId.flatMap { id ->
     someFlux.map { .. }.doOnNext { ... }.returnOnComplete(Mono.just(id))
}
```

I.e. I want to return `id` after `someFlux` has completed. The `returnOnComplete` function is made-up and doesn't exists (there's a `doOnComplete` function but it's for side-effects) which is why I'm asking this question. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `then(Mono<V>)` operator, as it does exactly what you want according to [the documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-):

> Let this `Flux` complete then play signals from a provided `Mono`.
>
> In other words ignore element from this `Flux` and transform its completion signal into the emission and completion signal of a provided `Mono<V>`. Error signal is replayed in the resulting `Mono<V>`.

For example:

```java
Mono
    .just("abc")
    .flatMap(id -> Flux.range(1, 10)
        .doOnNext(nr -> logger.info("Number: {}", nr))
        .then(Mono.just(id)))
    .subscribe(id -> logger.info("ID: {}", id));
```

Answer (score 4):

On top of `then(Mono<V>)`, as suggested by @g00glen00b, there is a `thenReturn(V)` method that is a bit shorter to write/clearer when your continuation is a simple `Mono.just`:

```
mono.then(Mono.just("foo")); //is the same as:
mono.thenReturn("foo");
```

Comment: `thenReturn` is only on `Mono`, not `Flux`